# Where can I find weak Pixelmon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

When I start up a new world of Pixelmon in Minecraft, all I have is a level 5 starter, and I'm surrounded by Pixelmon ranging from levels 10-45.  Finding a reasonable challenge is, in itself, a challenge.

Where can I go in the world to find weaker, lower-level challenges for my starter to grow and fight against?  Or am I stuck praying to find a low-level pokemon without accidentally running into a level 45?

Comment: Have you tried grinding Magikarp? Generally they only know splash so you could probably get away with taking down some of the higher level ones. http://wiki.pixelmonmod.com/index.php?title=Training_Pok%C3%A9mon#Training_weaker_Pok.C3.A9mon

Comment: @Pharap This is what I wound up doing.  Though Magikarp give out terrible EXP and are woefully slow to grind against.

Comment: Better you slow grinding them than them slow grinding you.

Comment: I've been tempted to try to participate in pixelmon development.  Maybe it would be a good idea to limit levels to `(distance_from_origin/64+2) ` to address this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant can't necessarily find weak pixelmon in a certain area, because the pixelmon that live and spawn in said area have randomly generated levels according to their current evolution stage and which pixelmon they are themselves. (Example: If a Weedle spawns In a plains biome, its level will be randomly picked from in-between 2-12)

My advice would be to do a lot of searching around for weak pixelmon to battle. If you still cant find any weak pixelmon, your you're better off creating a new world to play pixelmon in.

Answer (score 0):

A normal forest will do. Don't go to caves or other dimensions because the stronger ones are there. Depending on your type preference you can also find a beach and search there.

Comment: I haven't had much luck in either of these areas.  Are you certain there are low-level Pixelmon there?

Comment: yes I find a lot of them there. If you want to do training you can also find some zombies

Comment: May I add that there is no specific place to find low level Pokemon? The answer above is completely incorrect. You can find low level Pokemon everywhere, even though they might not be particularly common.

Comment: those are the most commen areas as I see it. I played it a lot when it was in the first stages.

Comment: Okay, but can I just say that everyone's world is different and different level Pokemon will spawn in different areas, according to world generation. ALSO, if you need help finding Pokemon, I would recommend the Poke radar mod. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just fight Magikarp lower than level 15 in the water. You should find levels 14, 13, 12, 11, 10 or 15. Level 15 Magikarp can use the move Tackle, watch out for them until your level is 15 or 16. Fight Pidgey, Caterpie, Spearow or Weedle.

Answer (score -3):

You can find weak Pokemon anywhere and everywhere, although they might be quite hard to come by. Hope that helped,